como saber el id de una cookie que se genera cuando se inicia sesión en next.js
Estoy intentando hacer un cierre de sesión, cuando el usuario inicia sesión se genera una cookie que se guarda en el  navegador, en esa cookie se guarda el id, con el valor del id puedo mandar a llamar a una api de cierre el cual ara que el estatus de conectado = true cambie false, pero no sé cómo poder consumir esa cookie.
En mi back en usuario.service tengo el login asi:
public static async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<string | null>
{
    const usuario = await this.obtenerUsuarioPorEmail(email);
    if (!usuario) return null;

    const esPasswordCorrecto = await bcrypt.compare(password, usuario.password);
    if (!esPasswordCorrecto) return null;

    usuario.conectado = true;
    await usuario.save();

    console.log(usuario.conectado);

    const token = jwt.sign({id: usuario._id, nombre: usuario.nombre, conectado: usuario.conectado, chats: usuario.chats}, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string, {expiresIn: '1d'});
    return serialize('token', token, {
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        path: '/',
    });
}

y en el front cuando inicio sesion guardo la cookie en el navegador de esta manera :
    const btnLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/usuarios/login', {
      email,
      password
    }, {withCredentials: true} );  
    console.log(response.data);
    Cookies.set('userId', response.data.userId);
    router.push('/homePage');
       } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
       }
     }

cuando inicio sesion el     conectado: { type: Boolean, default: false} pasa a true.
cree una funcion de logout el cual cuando la consumo hace el el true cambie a false
public static async logout(id: string): Promise<void>
    {
        await Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {conectado: false});
    }

el problema que tengo es que no he podido consumir el id que se genera aqui
async function btnCerrarSesion() {

    
    router.push("/landingPage");
  }

estoy implementando axios y la direccion es asi http://localhost:3001/usuarios/conected
pero hasta el momento no he logrado poder usar el id que se guarda.
